The term 'script:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
I am running a build pipeline YAML file in Azure where I have a powershell script that I want to run but I am facing the following error:

script: : The term 'script:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:_work_temp\32585f841520.ps1:7 char:3
script:
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (script::String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException



and the code is bellow:
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
- powershell: |
        $arr = Get-ChildItem '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Physical' |
        Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
        Foreach-Object {$_.Name}

            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=arr;]$arr"
  displayName: 'Powershell Script'

- powershell: |
    $string = "$(arr)"
    $Data=$string.split(" ")
    foreach($item in $Data){
      script:
      C:\C:\location_of_build_agent.exe "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\file_to_be_build" -c $item -buildMode "Rebuild"
      if (%errorlevel%==1) {exit 0} else {exit %errorlevel%}
      displayName: 'Run Build script for $item'
    }

The code should pass a list of configurations from an array to be Rebuilded.
I did try to run it also in CmdLine but without success.

You cannot create a pipeline task dynamically, i. e. while running the pipeline itself.

And there is no other way to run all configurations from a location without adding manually the config in the code?

I'm trying to make sense of your code but I just don't get it. Do you mind providing more context, i.e. what is your scenario? What is the content of the array? And what are you supposed to do with it?

I have a location where there are more folders, each folder is a configuration, I want to have a array with the names of the folders(configurations) and go through all of them and build them. if a new configuration is added in that folder there is no need to update the pipeline code.

I can reproduce the same error with your yaml, it's caused by you put script task inside powershell task. Please check the details below. Replace the real command to yours in the powershell task.


script: : The term 'script:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At D:_work_temp\32585f841520.ps1:7 char:3 script:

The direct cause is you put script task inside powershell task. The script keyword is read as a command but system cannot find it, then the error reported.
In DevOps pipeline, it's not supported to include one task in another task.
You are getting the folder name under Physical, in the 2nd PowerShell
task, run location_of_build_agent.exe against the folders. Not sure what's location_of_build_agent.exe.
Here is the sample for your reference, you can replace Write-host $item to your real command(location_of_build_agent.exe...).
- powershell: |
    $arr = Get-ChildItem '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Physical' |
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
    Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
    
    Write-Host $arr            # check the value
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=arr;]$arr"
  displayName: 'Powershell Script'

- powershell: |
    $string = "$(arr)"
    $Data=$string.split(" ")
    foreach($item in $Data){
      Write-host $item
    }
  displayName: 'Run Build script'


You are correct, was not working because I did put a task inside another task (script inside powershell) now I have to figure it out how to iterate all configurations and build them in a loop.

I did test the code and the "Write-host $item" command is looping correctly and shows all configurations from that path, but for some reason if I add my commands inside, after the first configuration that is build, it exits from the loop and continue running the rest of the tasks from the pipeline. my commands:  'C:\Automation\AS.PrepareBuild.exe C:\Automation\bin-en\AS.Build.exe "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Project.apj" -c $item -buildMode "Rebuild"
if ($LastExitCode -eq 1) {exit 0} else {exit $LastExitCode}'

Thanks @Adrian for the comment. You have {exit $LastExitCode} in the if expression which could end the task for 1st configuration, remove it for a check. Powershell task actually automatically check the exitcode, 1 for failure and 0 for succeed.

I have some warnings in the build of some configurations and powershell thinks that are errors and exit with code 1, for that reason I need this small logic if ($LastExitCode -eq 1) {exit 0} else {exit $LastExitCode} but I figure it out that this logic need to be outside of { } of foreach to continue looping and just after the loop to exitcode 0. Thanks for your contribution.


I have a location where there are more folders, each folder is a configuration, I want to have a array with the names of the folders (configurations) and go through all of them and build them. if a new configuration is added in that folder we don't need to update the pipeline code.

Making the pipeline dynamic, so that it doesn't need updating whenever a configuration is added or removed, seems beneficial. However, it might introduce unnecessary complexity to your code or pipeline.
So in order to decide how dynamic your pipeline should be I guess the most important question is:

How often are configurations added or removed?

If the configurations are added or removed frequently (e.g. every few weeks?) it might make sense to do something dynamic as you are already trying to do (or use Wade's workaround).
But, on the other hand, if the configurations don't change that often (e.g. 3 or 4 times per year?) consider something less dynamic but easier to understand and manage. For example, if your pipeline is properly structure it might be enough to just update a list of configurations defined as a parameter:
parameters:
  - name: configurations
    displayName: Configuration folders
    type: object
    default:
      - configA
      - configB
      - configC

steps:
  - ${{ each configuration in parameters.configurations }}:
    - script: |
        echo "Running build script for ${{ configuration }}"

        # other commands here
      displayName: 'Run build script for ${{ configuration }}'


I did also test your code variant, works as expected and can be used, as you recommend depending on how often the config list is updated or how clean I want the pipeline code I will take a decision on what I will use. Thanks for your contribution.

@Adrian no problem. Many times it's just not worth to sacrifice readability and maintenance for the sake of doing something more dynamic.
